# Apache reverse proxy: path not added in location redirects

Tags: apache, mod-proxy

While creating a simple reverse proxy, I'm struggling with a path-related issue that I cannot solve.

## Scenario

- I have a webserver on a frontend machine: [www.example.com](http://www.example.com).
- The frontend machine serves a local website (from /var/www/html)
- I created a new website and deployed it on port 'pppp' of an internal machine: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:pppp

## Goal

- The apache webserver on the frontend machine should serve content from xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:pppp whenever the user request is [www.example.com/path](http://www.example.com/path) (whatever internal subpath or subpage is requested).

From what I have read, to achieve this it should be as easy as adding the following directives in /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf within the `<VirtualHost>` tag:

```
ProxyPreserveHost On
ProxyPass "/path/" "http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:pppp/"
ProxyPassReverse "/path/" "http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:pppp/"
```

## Issues

- Requests of the form: [www.example.com/path/internal_page.html](http://www.example.com/path/internal_page.html) work fine
- Requests of the form [www.example.com/path/](http://www.example.com/path/) work fine

The problem is with requests of (sub-)paths with no trailing slashes. For example:

1. User requests [www.example.com/path/subpath](http://www.example.com/path/subpath) (no trailing slash!)
2. Frontend apache correctly redirects to internal machine
3. Internal machine (which has its own apache server) outputs (as it should) a 301 response. However, the "Location:" header in the response is "http://www.example.com/subpath/" instead of "http://www.example.com/path/subpath/".

What I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: I have the same problem. /path is not passed from the internal redirect. Was you able to deal with it?

Comment: Unfortunately I could't fix the problem. So I decided to switch to nginx, and everything worked fine immediately: nginx has a much easier configuration syntax (one line) to set up reverse proxies than apache2.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem. Managed to fix it by adding

```
<Location /mypath>
  ProxyPreserveHost On
  ProxyPass http://127.0.0.1:5000/mypath
  ProxyPassReverse http://127.0.0.1:5000/mypath
</Location>
```

Daemon that runs ASP.NET Core app contains **pathBase** parameter:

```
[Unit]
Description=My Web App

[Service]
WorkingDirectory=/opt/sites/MyWebApp
ExecStart=/usr/bin/dotnet /opt/sites/MyWebApp/MyWebApp.dll --pathBase=/mypath --urls=http://0.0.0.0:5000
Restart=always
RestartSec=10
KillSignal=SIGINT
SyslogIdentifier=trialkeygen
Environment=ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Production
Environment=DOTNET_PRINT_TELEMETRY_MESSAGE=false

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```